# Why wont my executable run when I type the name? (Mac OS X Mountain Lion) Mac OS X 10.8.2

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to run my program from XQuartz (X11) terminal and when I compile my executable doesn't have an asterisk on it and it won't run. It says that the command not found when I type the name. I was using Xcode at one point and I've downloaded Command-Line Tools. I'm VERY NEW TO C++ and Programming in General. Why is this and what do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: What commands are you using to compile your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've compiled it to a binary, in the folder in which the binary exists, run it with `./binary-name`. Normally, it should run. But if it says the binary is not executable (very unlikely), set the executable permission with `chmod +x binary-name`.

Usually, if the executable is not in `PATH`, you have to prepend it with `./` to run it.